VBA Application.Inputbox method removing additional Areas
I’m currently trying to create a macro where a dialog box prompt's the user to select multiple columns of data for further manipulation.
Currently I am using:
Private sub Button1_Click()
    Dim inp 
    inp = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=“Select columns”, Title:=“Not important”, Type:=8)
    
End sub

When this is run and the user inputs something like $A:$A,$D:$D ( a range with two areas) only the first area is actually captured ($A:$A) by the variable, using a watch in debug shows inp is only a 1 to X, 1 to 1  variant.
Is there a better method to use to get around this without prompting multiple dialogs or using a UserForm?
I have already attempted to use different types such as 2 (this partially works but requires the user to manually delete the auto filled "=" when a cell or column is selected) and 64 but the input results in type errors and have created a working version of my code using a UserForm (RefEdit.Value allows inputs to be taken as text and then I can turn that text into a range) but I was hoping to be able to do this with a single sub

Try to dimension inp as a Range and use a Set in front of inp = Application

Side note: if you want the .Value of a multi-area Range  (e.g. to store as an array), you need a loop.

Further to @Shrotter s comment, to access each selected non contiguous range, loop inp.Areas

Let the User Select a Range (Application.InputBox)

Most of the issues with your code are covered in your comments.

The Calling Procedure

At the bottom is a function that you could utilize in the following way:

Private Sub Button1_Click()
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = SelectRange("Select Columns", "Not Important", True, True)
    ' The 'True'-s are optional, so remove the annoying one(s) or use 'False'.
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' cancelled
    
    Dim arg As Range, i As Long
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        
        i = i + 1 ' remove 'i' if you don't need to count
        
        ' Do something more useful with each area range than e.g.,
        ' returning its index and address in the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G').
        Debug.Print i, arg.Address(0, 0)
        
    Next arg
    
End Sub

The Function
Function SelectRange( _
    ByVal Prompt As String, _
    ByVal Title As String, _
    Optional ByVal DisplaySuccessMessage As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal DisplayFailMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Range Selection"
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rg = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=Prompt, Title:=Title, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        If DisplayFailMessage Then
            MsgBox "You cancelled!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set SelectColumns = rg
    
    If DisplaySuccessMessage Then
        Dim aCount As Long: aCount = rg.Areas.Count
        MsgBox "You have selected the range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ on sheet """ & rg.Worksheet.Name & """." & vbLf _
            & "It contains " & aCount & " area" & IIf(aCount = 1, "", "s") _
            & ".", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Function

